# Found the ATV flipped over/knocked over/flipped on its side/knocked on its side

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> They found the ATV flipped over/knocked over/flipped on its
> side/knocked on its side.

If I want to describe that the ATV lay on its side after an accident, could I use "flipped over" or "knocked over" or would they both mean that the ATV lay with its wheels up?

Comment: ***flipped*** might be a bit "slangy", plus it normally implies *rendered **upside-down***. If something is *knocked over*, that normally implies it's on its side, not upside down. Note that ***knocked sideways*** usually implies *[forcefully] **moved** [to one side]* - but not necessarily "toppled over". So, for example, a car could be ***knocked sideways*** in a collision, but still end up with all 4 wheels on the ground.

Comment: They found the ATV upside down, wheels spinning.

Comment: You can use [rollover](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_rollover) as in [ROPS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_protection_structure). This is formal - a set abreviation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could that be an answer?

Comment: The correct verb would describe how it got that way. Was it knocked? Did it roll? If we don't know, then best to omit the verb: "They found the ATV on its side." "Flipped" implies the ATV is upside down on its roof, or that it went onto its side only after being upside down: "...flipped over **and** onto its side."

Comment: **Flip over** is commonly used to describe vehicles that have **turned over**. Knock over implies another vehicle.

Comment: Is an 'ATV' some kind of car?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'flipped' in pretty any context is very American. They do it with switches, I gather.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey All Terrain Vehicle. :)

Comment: @Lambie - oh, like an FWD?

Answer (score 0):

They found that the ATV had fallen over onto its side.

Comment: The question specifies it was knocked over in some way but your answer it purely about it falling.

Answer (score 0):

New York Times:

A 24‐year‐old stock car driver was killed tonight when his **car flipped over** during the first race at ShragriLa Speedway.

[flipped over](https://www.nytimes.com/1964/06/28/archives/carrace-accident-fatal.html)

At 9:40 a.m. yesterday, the rescue squad was called to the Long Island Expressway. A car **had flipped over**, pinning the driver inside.

[flipped over](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/06/20/nyregion/loving-the-job-and-even-the-risk-but-acutely-feeling-the-cost.html)

East London and Wessex Guardian

17th March 2017
One arrested after car '**flips several times'** on A406 North Circular at Walthamstow

[flipped over](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/06/20/nyregion/loving-the-job-and-even-the-risk-but-acutely-feeling-the-cost.html)

knocked over is OK too but it implies another actor (vehicle). If you say the vehicle was knocked on its side or over, something hit it. flipping over does not imply another actor, necessarily. Generally, flipped over and knocked over do imply that the vehicle's tires are facing upward. **However, if you add "*on its side*", it didn't go all the way over.**

I provided just three examples. There are many more of course.

turned over = wheels facing upwards
turned on its side= self-explanatory